# Warp circle inside out photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I want to know if there is a function in Photoshop to transform a circular cog wheel I have illustrated so that the cogs are pointing inwards instead of outwards. What I would need is something like a weighted puppet transform. Has any one done something similar?

**ADD:** I do not want ordinary gears.  I'm asking a function to warp an already existing gear so that the teeth that are now outwards turn inwards keeping the current graphic style of my gear.

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to GDSE! Please add an image of the cog wheel you have drawn and maybe also a quick sketch of how you want it to look. It's too hard to imagine what you are trying to achieve. Are you trying to somehow "mirror" an image towards the center? Sounds tricky.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  Can you please supply an image showing what you trying to alter?  Also how is the cog wheel constructed? Is it vector or raster?  Have you thought about using an actual vector image editor instead? The idea of creating a cog wheel in Photoshop seems a bit strange to be honest. It has extremely limited vector functionality. Creating an inside-out cog wheel would be easy in a vector image editor. [See example here](https://imgur.com/xMEMHTI)

Comment: Polar to rectangular conversion then flip and rectangular to polar conversion?

Comment: Thanks @joojaa this is how I did it! :)

Comment: @BillyKerr that is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

I went with the suggestion by @joojaa

`Filter -> Polar Coordinates...` I selected **Polar to rectangular** then I did the necessary transformations in this case `Edit -> Transform -> Warp` after that I returned to Polar coordinates using `Filter -> Polar Coordinates...` this time with the option **Rectangular to polar**.

Super easy. :)

[image]
[image]

Comment: If this is what's wanted accept your own answer to close the case. Otherwise this stays unsolved and cannot be found as solved.

Comment: It takes two days before I can accept it. Not sure why.

Comment: Some of us get addicted of web reputation. GDSE have blocked one easy way to get it fast.

Comment: Hehe I have a bit already over on stackoverflow. :P 7k plus so I think I should be trusted here as well. :)